Using an iterator to get the next(k) in FAISS similarity search
In FAISS after constructing an index (IVF, HNSW, or LSH) you can obtain the k-nearest neighbour based on a query q_x.
After my initial vector search in FAISS of let's say k = 50, I want to get more NN (i.e. 51, 52, 53..) until I satisfy the criteria I have set for the spatial calculations. (I am doing a combination of spatial and semantic similarity search.)
Is there a way you can do that getting the next(k) from the list of NN, without having to start the search all over again with k=51, then k=52 and so on?
import faiss
import numpy as np


d = 128  # dimension of vectors
index = faiss.IndexFlatL2(d)

# Add some vectors to the index
np.random.seed(123)
xb = np.random.random((1000, d)).astype('float32')
index.add(xb)

# Query vector
xq = np.random.random((1, d)).astype('float32')

def incremental_knn(index, xq, k, step_size):
    """Simulate an iterator-like behavior to get the next k-NN."""
    start = 0
    while True:
        # Incrementally increase the number of nearest neighbors
        k_next = start + step_size
        D, I = index.search(xq, k_next)  # Perform the search
        yield I[0][start:k_next], D[0][start:k_next]  # Return new results
        start = k_next  # Update starting point for the next iteration
        if k_next >= k:
            break

# Simulate fetching k-NN incrementally
step_size = 5  # Fetch 5 neighbors at a time
k = 20  # Total number of neighbors to fetch
for neighbors, distances in incremental_knn(index, xq, k, step_size):
    print(f"Next batch of neighbors: {neighbors}, distances: {distances}")

The only way I have found so far is to increase the k and do the calculations with the new vectors.

According to the FAISS tutorial on Pincone, IndexFlatL2 performs an exhaustive search, i.e., your query is compared to every vector in your index.
Therefore, I would expect that the runtime of the search is more or less independent from your choice of k. So, I would first test the influence of k on the runtime.
If a large k has neglible influence on the runtime, depending on your use case, I would just set k large enough or to the size of the data set.
If you use a more efficient index structure with an approximate KNN search, I do not think, an efficient incremental search is possible with FAISS. An alternative could be to use a range search.
